# Series of ln(x) for x>=1

Tags: logarithms

I need to develop $\mathrm{ln}(x)$ into series, where $x \geq 1$, and I don`t know how? In literature I only found series of $\mathrm{ln}(x)$, where:

1. $|x-1| \leq 1 \land x \neq 0$, $ \,\,\,\,\, \mathrm{ln}(x) = x - 1 - \dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2} + ...$
2. $|x| \leq 1 \land x \neq -1$, $ \,\,\,\,\, \mathrm{ln}(x+1) = x - \dfrac{x^2}{2}+ ...$

My problem is problem in area of fluid dynamics, and $x$ is non-dimensional coordinate and it signifies radial coordinate of annular tube (it starts in the center of the tube). At the wall of inner tube $x=1$, and at the wall of outer tube it only can be larger (and values ​​are not limited), because of that I need to fulfill a condition $x \geq 1$, for developing $\mathrm{ln}(x)$ into series.

===================================================================

**Additional explanation:**

I am looking for series of $\mathrm{ln}(x)$, where $x \geq 1$, because I have two integrals that I can't solve. That is, I can solve it in Wolfram Mathematica (I don't know how to solve it analyticaly), but in obtained solution appear `Gamma` and `ExpIntegralEi` function. These functions are formulated  over an imaginary number $z=x+iy$, and the solutions of my integrals represents the mass flow and the pressure field in the pipe. So, in my solution I got `Gamma` function, formulated over $z=x+iy$, on the other side I am sure that solution of mass flow does not contain any imaginary number. **Maybe the right question is: what is the behavior of `Gamma` and `ExpIntegralEi` function?** Could I look at these functions as black boxes? And if input is real number ($0i$) will the output be a real number?

Integrals:

$$\int \dfrac{ r^3 + r \mathrm{ln}r}{\mathrm{ln}r}\mathrm{d}r$$
$$\int \dfrac{r}{(\mathrm{ln}r)^{0.5} }\mathrm{d}r$$

Comment: There is no power series which only converges for $x \ge 1$. A power series which converges for arbitrarily large positive $x$ must also converge for arbitrarily large negative $x$ - and there is no such series for $\ln$. What do you need the series for? We may be able to help solve your real problem.

Comment: I concur with preferred_anon here. The domain of $\ln$ is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,:\,x\gt0\}$. Due to the natural boundary at 0, any series expansion of $\ln$ can only have a finite radius of convergence. If the center of expansion is $p$, then the radius of convergence is also $p$, meaning that the series converges for $0\lt{x}\leq2p$. But as such, it is not possible to give an expansion for $\ln$ that converges for every $x\geq1$. There is also no non-trivial asymptotic expansion for $\ln$. So you will need to provide more context here.

Comment: Are you restricting yourself to Laurent series?

Comment: I added explanation why I am looking for series of ln(x), shortly: because I have two integrals with ln(x) that I cannot solve.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I am allowed to assume that for all $y$ such that $1 \leq y < 2$, you are able to *satisfactorily* express $\ln(y)$ as a series.

Given $x$ such that $2 \leq x$, let $r$ denote the largest positive integer such that $2^r \leq x$.

Define $\displaystyle y = \frac{x}{2^r} \implies 1 \leq y < 2.$

Further, $\ln(y) = \ln(x) - r\ln(2)$.

Therefore, since $\ln(2)$ is a constant, as long as it is acceptable to be able to assume that $r$ may be computed in terms of $x$, then you are done.

One approach that you may or may not consider acceptable is to define $r$ as $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\right\rfloor,$ where $\lfloor a\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer $\leq a.$

Answer (score 1):

Render $y=(x-1)/(x+1), \therefore x=(1+y)/(1-y)$. With the aid of the familiar Maclaurin series render

$\ln x =\ln(1+y)-\ln(1-y)=[y-\dfrac{y^2}2+\dfrac{y^3}3-...]-[-y-\dfrac{y^2}2-\dfrac{y^3}3-...]$

$=2y+\dfrac{2y^3}3+\dfrac{2y^5}5+...$

$=\dfrac{2(x-1)}{x+1}+\dfrac{2(x-1)^3}{3(x+1)^3}+\dfrac{2(x-1)^5}{5(x+1)^5}+...$

which by the ratio test converges for all positive $x$. Also for all positive $\Re(x)$ in the complex domain.

Comment: +1 : Clearly better than my answer.